# How do I a conditional build through a make file?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How can we create selective objects by passing command line options to a make file?

My project structure is as follows.

```
Makefile
src/
include/
test/
```

The main file is under test dir & other C++ test code files, like abc1.cc abc2.cc, etc. also under test.

I want to build selective abcX.cc files into abcX.o files by passing appropriate argument to the `make` file.

I don't want to use my make as,

```
$ make ABC1=1 ABC2=1,
```

and put that ABC variable in ifeq in the make file.

Like,

```
ifeq ($(ABC1), 1)
  $(TESTPATH)/abc1.o
endif
```

Is there a practical approach?

Comment: How would you *like* to select the files you want to use? By group? By individual name? What does the rest of your makefile look like?

Comment: `make abc1.o`, perhaps? There's really no way to answer this without seeing the `Makefile` in question...

Comment: This question is unclear. Can you give a clear example of how you wish to invoke Make, and what you want it to do?

Comment: my question in simple words - I have 25 source files in test dir, out of them one is main.cc plus another are abc1.cc ... to... abc24.cc. What my target is I want to select module name from the drop down list(abcX list) of Jenkins & then based on selection I want to create that selected object & then link it to create target. help me ...how to create make file for such scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to create the same binary but use a different source for it by providing an option to make.

For this specific scenario, just use a [pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html) [phony/pseudo-target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) to make the final target:

```
# Create a pattern target, let's give it a name such that
# the pattern is obvious, such as ABC/<num>
.PHONY: ABC/%
ABC/%: main.cc $(TESTPATH)/abc%.cc
     g++ -o modtest $< # etc...
```

Then pass whatever number you wish to build to make with `make ABC/<num>`

```
$ make ABC/1
```

If, on the other hand you wish to produce individual binaries it's the same deal, but let the phony target depend on the final binary instead. It may look like this if the pattern is the same:

```
# Trigger the build for modtest-<num> with the target ABC/%
.PHONY: ABC/%
ABC/%: modtest-%
```

If you have more advanced dependencies from the pattern to the actual target you can specify variables that maps the pattern to whatever you need by e.g. using [target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html#Target_002dspecific) or [pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern_002dspecific.html#Pattern_002dspecific) specific variables:

```
# Set target specific variables to customize what to be built
ABC/1: OBJECTS=abc1 foo bar
ABC/2: OBJECTS=abc2
ABC/%: OBJECTS=% main
```